# Sheets code connected to a form. Doesn't run when new form entry is added

Tags: google-apps-script

I've written an autosorting script that's supposed to run every time my Google Sheet is edited. When I run the script manually it works, and when I edit a cell in the sheet manually it runs, but it doesn't run when a Google Forms adds a line to the sheet. Anyone who knows why? The moon language in the comments is swedish, but shouldn't matter.

```
//Startar funktionen när en ändring görs i dokumentet
function onEdit(event){
  //Om man sätter ascending = false sorterar scriptet i omvänd ordning.
  ascending = true
  //Hämtar det aktuella kalkylbladet och kollar vilka celler som ändrats.
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var editedCell = sheet.getActiveCell();
  //Ställer in vilken kolumn det ska sorteras på.
  var columnToSortBy = 1;
  //Ska egentligen hämta alla aktiva celler till variablen tableRange, men gör det inte. Kan förmodligen tas bort.
  var tableRange = sheet.getActiveRange()
  //Sköter själva sorteringen om något ändras i kolumn 1.
  if(editedCell.getColumn() == columnToSortBy){ 
    //Här ställer jag det som egentligen skulle vara tableRange från cellerna A2:G99 och sen görs själva sorteringen.
    var range = sheet.getRange("A2:G99");
    range.sort( { column : columnToSortBy } );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The on the edit if trigger only functions when a user edits a cell. You Might try using the on form submit event instead.

Answer (score 0):

First error that immediately sticks out is this:

```
ascending = true
```

should be

```
var ascending = true
```

Moving on to more nuanced problems. Your entire function is written to support manual edits on the spreadsheet. The `onEdit(event)` triggers whenever you make edits on the spreadsheet manually. In order to fire the script on a form submission, you must use an installable trigger (read [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#google_apps_triggers)).

If your script runs because of a form submission these will have no value:

```
var editedCell = sheet.getActiveCell();
var tableRange = sheet.getActiveRange()
```

as there is no Active Range or Active Cell. These refer to the cells you have selected in the Sheets editor when you trigger the script. You will need to rewrite it based on the form submit trigger (read about event handlers [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit))